# Tkinter- removing multiple selections from listbox

Tags: python, file, tkinter, listbox

I came here early and this guy help me with a code to have whats selected in the listbox

```
def selecionado(evt):
    global ativo
    a=evt.widget
    b=a.curselection()
    if len(b) > 0:
        seleção=a.curselection()[0]
         sel_text=a.get(seleção)
         ativo=[a.get(i) for i in a.curselection()]
    else:
        ativo=[]
```

But then my code to removing whatever is selected in the listbox wasn't working anymore, i can't figure out what to do. I just have this

```
def remover_membro(lista,part):
    lista.delete(ativo)
```

that is returning this error

```
_tkinter.TclError: bad listbox index
```

I want to remove whatever is selected in the list "lista" and in a file that is located in "part" like this:

name\tcode
name\tcode
name\tcode

The variable "ativo" is a list that pick names and codes with this formatation already

Answer (score 0):

Listbox deletion expects an index, not a list (or any other data type). Assuming `ativo` is a list of indexes (integers, specifically), `remover_membro` should look more like

```
for i in ativo:
    lista.delete(i)
```

If `ativo` isn't integers (i.e. it is the contents of the item), you can store indexes in a separate list since `.curselection()` gives the indexes (or you could only get the strings as needed via a list of indexes)

Comment: ativo is a tuple with the index selected, this solution didn't work out